# macOS Sonoma sound turned itself off

Tags: macos, audio, sonoma

I recently upgraded my home Macbook Pro from Ventura 13.1 to Sonoma 14.1.2. There was no problem with the sound until a few minutes ago, when suddenly the computer went silent, which I noticed when sending an email and confirmed by going to a music website. I did not mute the sound myself, and the Sound Preferences are set to internal speakers at maximum volume.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot already? Reboot?

Comment: Can you hear source material on earbuds/headphones plugged into the audio-out jack?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Steve and IconDaemon. I rebooted and my sound came back.